# how to get different size heatmaps with same row height's and width's

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm generating several heatmaps currently using `seaborn.heatmap` function.

The issue I'm having is that all the dataframes on which these heatmaps are being generated from have different row sizes, but they all have 10 columns. Essentially the shape of my dataframes which are being displayed in the form of a heatmap have variable amount of rows but a constant number of columns columns.

I'm trying to create heatmaps but the plots all look different sizes, even if I do `figsize=(10, len(df.index)/2.5)`, `df.index` here is the number of rows I have.

Is there a way to generate these heatmaps so that they all have the same width, same cell height, but just an increase or decrease in the overall height of plot if there are more rows or less rows. I want to be able to save all these plots separately.

Code I'm currently using which is not giving me the desired output:

```py
def plot_heatmap(df):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, len(df.index)/2.5))
    ax = sns.heatmap(
        df,
        vmin=0,
        vmax=1,
        cmap='coolwarm',
        annot=True,
        fmt='.3f',
        linewidths=.5,
        cbar=False,
        yticklabels=True,
        annot_kws={'alpha': 0.25},
    )

    # Remove axis labels, but keep tick labels
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    
    ax.set_title('Some Title')
    
    plt.savefig(
        'Some Title',
        dpi=300,
        bbox_inches='tight'
    )
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Iterate through each virus group and plot the heatmap
for df in group_dfs:
    plot_heatmap(df)
```

Comment: @JohanC Any hint on how I could account for the varying amount of rows in the heatmap, the row heights seem to differ when there are different shapes of the dataframe.

Comment: @JohanC the row heights are consistent. The issue is when I look at the output for a heatmap with 10 rows it seems smaller than the heatmap with say 4 rows, ratio of the plot size wise, otherwise this works well.

Comment: Does one of the suggested solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

## Fixed height per row, saving with tight bbox

Part of the `figsize` goes to the tick labels of the x and y axes. Instead of letting seaborn create the ax automatically, you could explicitly create `ax = plt.axes((left, bottom, width, height))`. That way, the heatmap part will always have the same width and a height directly proportional to the figure's height.

The following code creates an example of 4 and of 10 rows, which look identical. When saving to file, the superfluous whitespace is cut off.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def plot_heatmap(df, some_title):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, len(df.index) / 2.5))
    ax = plt.axes((0.1, 0.2, 0.85, 0.6))
    ax = sns.heatmap(df, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='coolwarm', annot=True, fmt='.3f',
                     linewidths=.5, cbar=False, yticklabels=True, annot_kws={'alpha': 0.6})
    ax.set_title(some_title)

    plt.savefig(f'{some_title}.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()

# Iterate through each virus group and plot the heatmap
for row_len in (4, 10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(row_len, 10), columns=[*'abcdefghij'])
    plot_heatmap(df, f'{row_len} rows')
```

[image: 4 rows]

[image: 10 rows]

## Fixing height in inches for each row, and top and bottom

Here is an approach to calculate the size of the figure, supposing fixed heights per row, and for the top and bottom.  `fig.subplots_adjust()` is used to position the plot region.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def plot_heatmap(df, some_title):
    row_height_inches = 0.25
    axes_height_inches = row_height_inches * len(df)
    inches_bottom = 0.35
    inches_top = 0.3
    fig_height_inches = axes_height_inches + inches_bottom + inches_top

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, fig_height_inches))
    ax = sns.heatmap(df, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='coolwarm', annot=True, fmt='.3f',
                     linewidths=.5, cbar=False, yticklabels=True, annot_kws={'alpha': 0.6})
    ax.set_title(some_title)

    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=inches_bottom / fig_height_inches,
                        top=(fig_height_inches - inches_top) / fig_height_inches,
                        left=0.05, right=0.98)
    plt.show()

# Iterate through each virus group and plot the heatmap
for row_len in (4, 10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(row_len, 10), columns=[*'abcdefghij'])
    plot_heatmap(df, f'{row_len} rows')
```